# Nexus Repository Issue while uploading artifact using maven command

Tags: maven, nexus

As you have mentioned above I have updated pom like

```
<distributionManagement>

     <repository>
         <id>deployment</id>
         <name>deployment</name>
         <url>http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases</url>
     </repository>

     <snapshotRepository>
         <id>snapshots</id>
         <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
         <url>http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
     </snapshotRepository>

</distributionManagement>
```

and also changed the `settings.xml` to something like this

```
        <server>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <username>deployment</username>
            <password>deployment123</password>
        </server>

        <server>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <username>deployment</username>
            <password>deployment123</password>
        </server>
```

But when I'm deploying using the `mvn deploy` maven command I'm getting an exception like this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project Test: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer ar
tifact Test:Test:jar:0.0.1 from deployment (http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8080/nexus-
webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases/Test/Test/0.0.1/Test-0.0.1.jar. Return code is: 401 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project Test: F
ailed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact Test:Test:jar:0.0.1 from deployment (http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases): Faile
d to transfer file: http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases/Test/Test/0.0.1/Test-0.0.1.jar. Return code is: 401
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:314)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:151)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:445)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:132)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact Test:Test:jar:0.0.1 from deployment (http://localhost:8
080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases/Test/Test/0.0.1/Tes
t-0.0.1.jar. Return code is: 401
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:195)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact Test:Test:jar:0.0.1 from deployment (ht
tp://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases/Tes
t/Test/0.0.1/Test-0.0.1.jar. Return code is: 401
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:156)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact Test:Test:jar:0.0.1 from deployment (http://localho
st:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases/Test/Test/0.0.1
/Test-0.0.1.jar. **Return code is: 401**
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:267)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:334)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:136)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact Test:Test:jar:0.0.1 from deployment (http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9
.2/content/repositories/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases/Test/Test/0.0.1/Test-0.0.1.jar. Return
code is: 401
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:858)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:849)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:773)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.put(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:385)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:241)
        ... 24 more
**Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.2/content/repositories/releases/Test/Test/0.0.1
/Test-0.0.1.jar. Return code is: 401**
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.finishPutTransfer(LightweightHttpWagon.java:205)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.putTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:413)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.transfer(AbstractWagon.java:392)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.AbstractWagon.putTransfer(AbstractWagon.java:365)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.put(StreamWagon.java:163)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:734)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.put(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:384)
        ... 25 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Does the deployment UserID and Password not have privileges to upload artifact in nexus using `maven deploy`? **I'm using Nexus 1.9.2** Does Nexus Professional only have privileges to upload?. Please guide me.

Answer (score 5):

Also, make sure there's not already an artifact of the same name & version there :) If you are deploying to a release Nexus repository, you cannot overwrite an existing file.

Comment: How do I prevent maven to upload the release file to Nexus when the file already exists?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can - but Nexus won't let you if you try.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I resolved it with just making the new SNAPSHOT version after nexus release was uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Error code 401 means you not authorized to upload the file. Check user and pass first by logging in, then check permissions.  Another gotcha is that the "deployment" is often disabled.

Comment: I am seeing similar issue but I get 400. 
Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
 at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer

Comment: @Nirmal 400 suggests a badly formed request. Suggest you post a new question with more details on what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your Nexus url is correct. Localhost is probably a bad choice and normally Nexus is using the context nexus.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue if your are running Hudson local on your machine, it uses maven settings.xml of his own file structure in the user directory because of windows. I always modified the settings.xml in my maven directory. When I copied the modified xml to the hudson folder. It worked.You can than find the Hudson settings.xml here:

> `C:\Users\Username\.hudson\maven\slavebundle\bundled-maven\conf`

If you want to check if this is the solution for your problem, then your local build via maven works but any Hudson job done fails with error 401. I tried also to change nexus user setting (creation of new users, change passwort settings) due different posts suggested it, but that was not the solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You must to encrypt the password:

```
mvn --encrypt-password deployment123

{JipXtsVVaqAHauN0TGDIRWwOmjCdJ3+tdNl7T/nY7hQ=}


<username>deployment</username>
<password>{JipXtsVVaqAHauN0TGDIRWwOmjCdJ3+tdNl7T/nY7hQ=}</password>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this 401 problem by upgrading Maven from 3.0.5 to 3.3.3 version.

I found this link [What to do when Nexus returns '401'](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/11/what-to-do-when-nexus-returns-401) talking about mvn version update.

> - Use the latest version of Maven, as there is a known issue regarding 401: 
>     [MNG-4469](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4469)